# Adaptive control

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, adaptive-control, model-predictive-control

I have a question regarding the derivation of the adaptive law. Why do we derive the adaptive law-based parameter estimation algorithm in continuous time? Can we derive it in discrete time?

Comment: Yes, of course, there has been a lot of work on the adaptive control of discrete-time systems. See for instance https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=adaptive+control+discrete+systems&btnG=&oq=adaptive+control+disc

Comment: Why do we use the continuous-time cost function then? I got confused in this part!

Comment: It is a choice to work either in continuous-time or in discrete-time. But systems are often intrinsically in continuous-time, which motivates the use of continuous-time methods. Without more details about the resources you are using, it is not possible to give a better answer, there is not only one adaptive control.

Comment: It's not really a question of "deriving THE law", but of coming up with A rule and showing it provides stability. That said, the references in the comment by KBS do exactly that.